# Unable to find Magento Connect Manager in magento ver 2.0.2

Tags: magento-2.0

This is system tab of my magento admin panel where connect manager should be, but it is not there:
[image: ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Magento Connect for Version 2.0 for it to connect up to even if you had the tab entry.

It's all Github and developers access for module installation. Composer is the installation method of choice currently. Magento Connect is futureware for somewhere out there on a later Magento 2.x